# Code with local db works fine but it fails in env with the error No value present

Tags: spring

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at com.publicis.sapient.ppc.analyticstool.createec2instance.service.EC2InstanceService.addTags(EC2InstanceService.java:146) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.publicis.sapient.ppc.analyticstool.createec2instance.service.EC2InstanceService.createEc2Instance(EC2InstanceService.java:246) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.publicis.sapient.ppc.analyticstool.createec2instance.service.EC2InstanceService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$802d3e99.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
```

Below is the line of code where the error comes:

```
String userName = userRepository.findById(1).get().getName();
```

Comment: userRepository.findById(1) is returning Optional.empty().

Comment: so, before call `get()`, check is the value `isPresent`

Comment: Tried that...  the value is not present...   but actually the value is present in the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the value is present before calling `get()`, otherwise the value must not be present and you get the error.

```
Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(1);
if (user.isPresent()) {
    String userName = user.get().getName();
}
```

Comment: Have tried that. But it never enters if condition even in this case. Since the rows are present in db it should ideally fetch the row....   it works fine in local with same details

Comment: Ok, but in the local database the user ID 1 exists. But seems that in production environment doesnt exists